# Create Google Map from location (No by Latitude/Longitude)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

currently I have a database with some addresses, I want to make a php script to automatically generate google maps based on the addresses stored in my MySQL database.

That is, just as if I manually take directions and copy/paste in https://maps.google.com/ searchbox, and click on search. As if a person do it manually.

I have seen an example, and see that they always use latitude and longitude, I do not want to do that, because I do not know this information, I want to search by address (stored in my DB).

I know about JavaScript and PHP, but I've never worked with Google APIs (are it necessary?).

Is there any tutorial to generate a Google map based on an address?

Please forgive my horrible way to write English.

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a tutorial, but the place to definitely look into is [Google's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). You can provide an address, which will convert to a longitude and latitude. You can then use the lat/lng to find the exact address on the map. If you have not done so already, then you should follow this tutorial to make a [Google Dev account](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: Also, here is how you can place a [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) that points to the address on the google map. I hope anything I mentioned helps!

Comment: Thanks Stephen! The information you provided to me was very helpful!
I have solved my problem with @geocodezip